# ora 01858 while inserting data from other table with same schema in same database

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I am an application programmer but currently I have a situation in which I need to copy a huge amount of data which is collected for 1 month say approx 653 GB of data from the table in one database to exact similar table in other database (both oracle 11G). Each row size is approx 150 bytes. So the number of rows are approximately 4000 millions. I am not joking.

I have to do this. The table which holds this data (source table) is partitioned based on date column. So there is a partition for each day of the  month and hence in total 31 partitions for December month.

The target db is partitioned  based on month. So there is a single partition in the target db for complete december month.

I have chosen to copy the data over db link and with the help of dba's I created a db link between this 2 databases.

I have a store procedure in target db  which accepts input parameter as (date, tablename). What this procedure does is it creates a temporary table in target db with name as tablename and copies all the data from the source db for the given date into this temporary table in target database. I have done it successfully for 2-3 days. Now I want to insert this data in the temporary table into actual table in the same target database. For that I executed following query:

```
insert into schemaname.target_table select * from schemaname.temp_table;
```

But I am getting folloowing ORA error.

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Both the tables have exact same table defination. I searched over internet for copying data and found the above query to insert as simplest. But I don't understand the error. Searching for this errors show it is has something to do with date column. But shouldn't it work as both the tables have same table structure?

Data types used in the table are  varchar2(x), date, number(x,y), char(x).

Please help me  to get over this error. Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Are the columns in the same order in both tables?

Comment: how to check the order. is that what we get by desc tablename?

Comment: It should be although I don't have oracle here.  Another way would be to do select * from target_table and select * from temp_table and make sure the columns are in the same order.

Comment: @chammu, yes `desc tablename` will give you the column order. There must be a difference, otherwise the error wouldn't be happening.

Comment: Yes you are correct. there a difference.

Comment: My table has got 100 columns so do I need to mention this all the columns in the select and insert statement?

Comment: If one table is a temp table, just do a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement, which will make sure you have the same structure (even if somebody changes the structure of the main table). After that action, you can still do a `TRUNCATE`, and then perform your `INSERT`

Comment: I didn't get you. can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: I need to copy all this data by EOD tomorrow And I have already loaded about 300 G of data into temporary tables. so I would not prefer deleting or reinserting data into other temporary tables. I need to just insert from this temp tables to the main table.

Comment: Isn't there any other simple solution to avoid this problem except manually giving the column names?

Comment: write select that will get you all column names for your query to avoid manual typing

Comment: So when you wrote "exact similar table" what you actually meant was "structurally different table"?

Comment: I have completed my task by giving column names in the select and insert statement. But I would like to know if there exists any simple alternative for the above mentioned situation.

Answer (score 0):

It means your schemaname.temp_table table has some non-numeric value which doesn't inserted in your new table. Did schemaname.temp_table table populated with some script or any automated tool? There is possibility of empty space or junk character inserted in schemaname.temp_table. Kindly check once again using any sql tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the case. I have completed the task by giving column names in select and insert statement. The problem was due to the column order.